# angularjs: navigator back button or history back

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use browser back button to navigate to last page accessed by user.
In Jquery i can use below code.

```
 function onBackKeyDown() {
        history.go(-1);
        navigator.app.backHistory();
    }
```

I want to achive the same by Angular. But i am very new to angular so, looking for advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
   function onBackKeyDown() {
        history.go(document.referrer);
        navigator.app.backHistory();
    }
```

`document.referrer` will give you last url.